# Weird issue with NSWindow contentView on Mavericks

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-mavericks

I'm an experienced iOS developer that has recently embarked on a journey to build his first Mac OS app. So far so good, but I've hit upon a weird issue.

I have a single window application (initiated from the default MainMenu.xib file), that pushes some NSViews (from custom NSViewControllers that I've created) on to the NSWindow contentView.

This is working well on my Macbook Air running Mountain Lion, and on another Macbook Pro retina running the latest version of Mavericks. However, I have a third device running Mavericks as well, and I just get a blank screen window there with no views.

So this is the window structure:

```
NSWindow (custom NSWindow object, initiated with NSBorderlessWindowMask)
    --> NSWindow has a background view, with a solid colour
```

Then, I have following structure for the content that needs to be displayed in window:

```
NSViewController (main)
    --> NSViewController sub 1. View is added to the ViewController above
    --> NSViewController sub 2. View is added to the ViewController above
    --> NSViewController sub 3. View is added to the ViewController above
```

Then I add the main NSViewController (that contain the subparts of the view) to the contentView of the window

```
self.mainViewController = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];

[self.window.contentView addSubview: self.mainViewController.view];
[self.window.contentView setNeedsDisplay:YES];

self.mainViewController.view.frame = ((NSView*) self.window.contentView).bounds;
```

On the Mavericks device where I'm having issues with, I just get to see the NSWindow plus its background view. On all the others everything is working fine.

Comment: Where you you create the other view controllers? In the xib or manually?

Comment: The other views are created in the MainViewController, also loaded from XIB file (through code). They're added as subviews of the MainViewController.

Comment: If the other view controllers are at the root level of your xib make sure to use "strong" when creating outlets as they will not be retained.

Comment: Sub viewcontrollers are init in a similar way to mainViewController (initWithNibName etc) in MainViewController and these viewcontroller views are then added to self.view. The XIB file of MainViewController does not contain direct references to the XIBs of the subviews. They're also retained properly, should be no issues with that.

Comment: What are the chances the problem system doesn't have the NIB resources in the bundle?  Everything built and installed the same?

Comment: Close to none, I'd say. We're deploying everything through a single .app file to all the systems. Coming from iOS I'm not too familiar with Mac programming, is there something I'm doing that is sort of out of the ordinary with the window/viewcontrollers?

Comment: I don't think so.  Is the problem system localized differently than the other two?

Comment: Working systems are both EN localized, but the non working one is NL localized.

Comment: Aha.  initWithNibName looks for resources in the language-specific dirs, then the generic Resources.  Perhaps your nibs are english-only.

Comment: Ah. The XIBs don't seem to be localized, but MainMenu is set to Base. I've also changed the NL system to EN, but that doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: SOLVED!!!! Thank you very much. I created a Base localization for the subview(s), and it's working. Odd issue. Please post this as an answer  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm sure I localize things less often than you, but I suspected first that missing NIB resources was the issue, and then that localization was the issue because the NIBs weren't loading and `initWithNibName:bundle` does look for localized NIBs.

Sounds like you needed Base localization for the subviews to ensure they appear everywhere, which I guess is fairly odd.